# Permutation Numbers

Tags: eclipse

Hello I have this problem to solve and I can only use :String and Scanner.This is the problem : The user enters a number and I have to return the maximum number that can be made using permutations of this number Any ideias?

Comment: Here's a number: 123432. What's the answer? How did you find the answer? If you did find it, then you have a strategy. So you just need to implement this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the digits from the string and sort them in descending order.